# Can a menu item be added to a tabbed action bar on a narrow screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have a tabbed action bar on a narrow screen that renders as shown in the right-hand image below:

[image]

I'd like to also squeeze an "always show" menu item to the main action bar.  However, when I introduce the menu item to the layout, a second action bar containing just the menu item is created directly below the tabbed bar.

Of course, I've disabled the action bar icon and title (with `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` and `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`) to get the single-line action bar before adding the menu item.

Is it possible using the standard action bar to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Adam Powell's response on the relevant Google+ thread:

> To answer the original question, no, what you want is not a supported behavior of the action bar.